# automated testing with MTM but without build server

Tags: windows-7, tfs, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

Is there a way for automated testing with Microsoft Test Manager on a local machine? Without an build server?
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can kick of the test cases using the command line tcm.exe to run the test cases automatically.
If they are set for automation, they run locally.